# I have an issue with fallback in an Icecast setup

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, icecast

I was hoping one of you guys could help me with the following issue as I'm quite new to icecast.

Goal:
The ability to have a stream supplying music 24/7, with the ability to get DJ's into the mix without listeners need to change to a different link/stream.

Setup:
I have icecast2 2.3.1 installed on a Windows Server 2008 server, and I have configured three mountpoints, Live, DJ and Autostream.
'Live' is the mountpoint that my listeners should connect to.
'DJ' is the mountpoint that my DJ's connect to in order to do their sets.
'Autostream' is the mountpoint playing music 24/7.

Issue:
I cannot get the fallback to work between the three mountpoints.
Unless I have a stream connected directly to the mountpoint, my error log tells me it doesn't exist.

Here's my config so far:

```
    <mount-name>/autostream.mp3</mount-name>
    <hidden>1</hidden>
    <public>0</public>
</mount>

<mount>
    <mount-name>/dj.mp3</mount-name>
    <fallback-mount>/autostream.mp3</mount-name>
    <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
    <hidden>1</hidden>
</mount>

<mount>
    <mount-name>/live.mp3</mount-name>
    <fallback-mount>/dj.mp3</fallback-mount>
    <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
    <hidden>0</hidden>
</mount>
```

Have I misstyped something or am I just not getting how the fallback setting works?

Answer (score 0):

It seemed the fallback system works perfectly just as is.

After having left it alone for a bit, I came back to look at the config again and noticed I had left the original --> (end of comment) line sitting after my row of mountpoints, basically commenting the entire setup out of the config.

Needless to say, when I moved the --> to the correct place in my config file, everything works now.

Added changes: Changed the mountpoint names back to the plain, without the .mp3 suffix and tidied up the code a little bit, getting rid of the  sections on all but the autostream mountpoint.